# Make a <div> with z-index > 0 take up 0 space in zero-layer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `<table>` in which I open a context menu when the user clicks any of the rows, by adding a `<div>` containing the menu directly to the `<tr>` (yes, it's not valid HTML, I know...).

My problem is, that when the menu appears, it takes up nonzero space in the table row, thus slightly shifting the widths of all the `<td>`s, although the entire menu has a `z-index: 1` (or higher, in the case of submenus).

I need the menu `<div>` inside the `<tr>` to handle css coloring (the entire `<tr>` is highlighted when the menu is under the mouse, which doesn't work if the menu isn't inside the `<tr>`...), but I don't want the columns to jump around when I open the menu.

Is there a way to force the `<div>` to have no extent at all in the `z-index: 0` layer, although it does take up space in the upper layers?

**Update**

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcztt4wm/1/) that reproduces the error. It turns out it was also related to the styles in Twitter Bootstrap - without them, the shifting goes away. I need them, though, as our UI is designed with it...

Comment: A jsFiddle reproducing the problem would be helpful

Comment: Show your code and we can show you how to do this properly! There is probably no need for hacky markup :)

Comment: Crap. The jsFiddle didn't save correctly, so the link goes to a partial example. I'll update momentarily...

Comment: There. Fiddle should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append to the last td in the row. Something like - `$(this).children('td:last-child').append`. There doesn't appear to be any problem with the colors.

### Complete Example

```js
(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('tr').on('click', function(evt) {
            $('.menu').hide().remove();
            $(this).children('td:last-child').append(
                $('<div>')
                    .addClass('menu')
                    .append('<p>This is the context menu</p>')
                );
            
            evt.stopPropagation();
        });
        
        $('body').on('click', function(evt) {
            $('.menu').hide().remove();
        });
    });
})();
```

```css
tr:hover, tr:hover td {
    background: blue !important;
    color: white;
}

.menu {
    height: 100px;
    width: 80px;
    background-color: green;
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>First column</td>
        <td>Second column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First column</td>
        <td>Second column</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This helped me get part of the way there. In my actual application, the position is determined by the location of the mouse click, but I was able to modify your code to do that: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcztt4wm/2/)

Comment: @TomasLycken - Oh, so the shift *was* caused by appending the menu to the tr. `position: fixed` will work fine with the menu appended to the last td of the row.